# Spring Boot Application Auto Shut Down

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have this really simple main class in a Spring Boot Demo

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebSpringDemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext =
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");
    }
}
```

This is my spring-config xml file(just to make a bean):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean id="myBean" class="com.example.webspringdemo.Cat" init-method="init" destroy-method="destroy" />
</beans>
```

When I start the main method, everything works fine, but it seems like it didn't make any web-related thing, and it shut down automatically. I was expecting it to run continously (until I manually stop by using IDE or use the close() method) on port 8080 so I can add further more complicated code. But the program just shut down after it makes the bean. Like here is all the output(it didn't even generate the "info" lines):

```
Init

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I am using IntelliJ.

Comment: An ApplicationContext is not an instance of a Spring Boot app. Nor is the @SpringBootApplication annotation, which configures classpath scanning and dependency injection. You are creating an object which does nothing and the main method completes, exiting the program. You need to actually run a Spring app, see this example: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.html

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, you need to run the spring boot app in this manner.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebSpringDemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

If you want to run additional logic after startup, you can create a application listener class like this and place the logic there:

```
public class MyApplicationListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        // Your additional logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Per my comment, your application is exiting because you are not explicitly starting a Spring Application. The idiomatic way of doing this is using the static method [SpringApplication.run](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.html#run(java.lang.Class%5B%5D,java.lang.String%5B%5D)).

An ApplicationContext is not an instance of a Spring app, but is still a core component of the IoC framework. It's used internally by Spring to manage bean lifecycles, autowire dependencies, provide scheduling functionality, etc. Only in advanced use cases would I advise creating or modifying custom `ApplicationContext` instances, as Spring manages this class for the developer.

Last word of advice, the XML syntax is typically deprecated in favor of annotation based bean registration. In practice, this is easier to read and understand. Here's an example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebSpringDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebSpringDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    Cat createCat() {
        return new Cat();
    }
}

@Component
class Zoo {
    private Cat cat;
    
    public Zoo(Cat cat) { // an instance of Cat is autowired here!
        this.cat = cat;
    }
}
```